# Concatenate an array and an IO object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, concatenation, iterable

I want to iterate over a hardcoded list of strings, and when they run out, I want to continue to iterate over STDIN.

Is there a way to concatenate two iterables, or something like that?

Guava provides this sort of thing for Java:
[http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

From that page: *Combines two iterables into a single iterable. The returned iterable has an iterator that traverses the elements in a, followed by the elements in b. The source iterators are not polled until necessary.*

If I had a "concat" method, I would do something like this:

```
my_lines = ["line1", "line2", "line3"]

(my_lines.each).concat(STDIN.each).each do
    |line|
    puts "LINE = |#{line}|"
end
```

Does ruby provide something out of the box to do this? If not, is there a popular idiom for accomplishing this?

Comment: use `#gets` method of STDIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `concat` method yourself:

```
class Enumerator
  def concat(*enums)
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      self.each { |i| y << i }
      enums.each { |e| e.each { |i| y << i } }
    end
  end
end

my_lines = ["line1", "line2", "line3"]

(my_lines.each).concat(STDIN.each).each do
    |line|
    puts "LINE = |#{line.chomp}|"
end
# LINE = |line1|
# LINE = |line2|
# LINE = |line3|
=> kkk
# LINE = |kkk|
=> dsf;sdlf
#LINE = |dsf;sdlf|
```